# Is asking about the web development process in a company and tools/software required on topic?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to know about the whole professional web development process (PHP - MySQL) from getting the client, to delivery of the project, the full cycle of web development and which software (free software) can be used?

May the question be asked here? If not where can I ask the question with its elaborate version?

Comment: @{close voter} No. Not off-topic. That you don't like a [[meta-tag:site-recommendation]] question doesn't mean it should be closed.

Comment: @michaelb958 - I think it was just flagged.

Answer (score 4):

Your question doesn't belong, but not because it's off topic: the problem is that your question is too broad. You're effectively asking the equivalent of:

> How do skyscrapers get built?

Which has no one particular answer (there are different methods to follow), involves a *tremendous* amount of work going through several teams' and organisations' hands, and so on.

Large articles could be written tackling this topic that *still* don't fully answer your question.

Comment: I'll scrap my draft then... large articles can be written about any of the sub-headings that don't even come close to answering the question...

Comment: Can i atleast know the development process after designers deliver the design/look of a web site to the developers ,  to submiting the finished project to the project manager.Developing lets say being done by more than one guy, and it involves testing , debugging , database design etc. May i ask what are the steps followed by a company or if i want to be a freelancer and what are the tools required to do it efficiently?( free onces)

Comment: @BabaKamdev Go ask... a company?

Comment: @BabaKamdev Still way too broad.  I've been at a lot of different companies, and they all did it a different way. Perhaps Quora is your best bet?